# How to use an exported model from google colab in Pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm, google-colaboratory

I have a LSTM Keras Tensorflow model trained and exported in .h5  (HDF5) format. 
My local machine does not support keras tensorflow. I have tried installing. But does not work.

Therefore, i used google colabs and exported the model.

I would like to know, how i can use the exported model in pycharm

Edit : I just now installed tensorflow on my machine

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you will need TensorFlow to use the exported model.

Comment: ive installed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer :

I ve exported the model as follows

```
model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/model.h5')
```

Then i downloaded the file and saved in the folder where my other codes are. I have installed tensorflow.

Next i load the code and predicted using the saved model as follows.

```
import keras
model=keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/model.h5')
model.predict(instace)
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need keras and tensorflow to use the model.

Comment: ive installed it now

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct but it misses that you first need to mount the "**/content/drive**"

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then you can save the weights of the model:

```
model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```

..or even save the whole model :

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Once done, disconnect your mounted point using:

```
drive.flush_and_unmount()
```